# Convert a string containing integers to list of integers

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

What is the shortest way to convert a string containing integers separated by spaces to a list of integers?

- input : "-3 1 5 8 10"
- output : [-3, 1, 5, 8, 10]

I regularly face this situation and I wanted to know if there is a better way than (24 bytes):

```
list(map(int,s.split()))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using *map* is way shorter than any of the ways I mentioned. You should do that.

Instead of calling `list(...)`, you should use `[*...]` (21 bytes):

```
[*map(int,s.split())]
```

Or even better, if you switch to python 2, `map` will always return a list. (18 bytes):

```
map(int,s.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/pfbKuka6xgqGCqYKFgaKDElWMb8z83sUAjM69Ep1ivuCAns0RDU/N/QRFQQCNHkwvCKKksSAXyNP8DAA)

Original Post:

---

The straightforward way is going to be 26 bytes

```python
[int(n)for n in s.split()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fbKuka6xgqGCqYKFgaKDElWMb8z86M69EI08zLb9IIU8hM0@hWK@4ICezREMz9n9BEUguR/M/AA)

However, if a tuple is acceptable instead of a list, we could use a trick to shave one byte off leaving us with 25 bytes

```python
eval(",".join(s.split()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fbKuka6xgqGCqYKFgaKDElWMb8z@1LDFHQ0lHSS8rPzNPo1ivuCAns0RDU1Pzf0FRZl6JRo7mfwA)

This can be shortened even more with the **replace** function (24):

```python
eval(s.replace(' ',','))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fbKuka6xgqGCqYKFgaKDElWMb8z@1LDFHo1ivKLUgJzE5VUNdQV0HCDU1/xcUZeaVaORo/gcA)

and even more with iterable unpacking (22):

```python
eval(s.replace(*" ,"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fbKuka6xgqGCqYKFgaKDElWMb8z@1LDFHo1ivKLUgJzE5VUNLSUFHSVPzf0FRZl6JRo7mfwA)

If you truly need a list, you can wrap it in `[*...]`. This is still shorter than the straightforward way by 1 byte:

```python
[*eval(s.replace(*" ,"))]
```